# How do I query a parent table for two distinct child rows?

Tags: sql

Given these two tables, with a to-many relationship from Order to LineItem:

```
Order
-----
Order_id (primary key)

LineItem
--------
LineItem_id (primary key)
Order_id (foreign key to Order)
price
productCode
```

How would I find Orders with at least one line item where price = 10.00, and a *different* line item with productCode = 12345?

Comment: We seem to have some interpretation differences among the answers. To me it sounds like the condition should be satisfied by an item with price=10 and productcode=12345, as long as there's a second item with productcode=12345 to be the "different" item.

Comment: That's correct. The conditions would even be met for an Order with 2 LineItems, _both_ with price=10 and productCode=12345.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want 2 different items, you need to join the lineitem table twice and forbid them to have the same primary key.

```
select distinct o.order_id
from order o
join lineitem item1
  on item1.order_id = o.order_id
join lineitem item2
  on item2.order_id = o.order_id
 and item2.lineitem_id != item1.lineitem_id
where item1.price = 10
  and item2.productcode = 12345
```

Comment: Credit to @Conrad Frix (I think) for the `distinct` which I didn't originally have in my answer. After I stole it, that other answer was deleted...

Comment: I deleted it since I liked `item2.lineitem_id != item1.lineitem_id` better than my solution of `item1.productcode <> 12345`

Comment: Thanks a bunch for such a fast response! I need to get used to the idea of joining on the same table more than once.

Comment: Could the line "and item2.lineitem_id != item1.lineitem_id" be in the "where" clause instead of the second join?

Comment: Since these are inner joins, it doesn't matter what's in the `ON` clauses and what's in the `WHERE` clause. The result will be the same if you rearrange it. I just put them where they seemed most logical to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use UNION and combine the two queries.  So something like this (untested)

```
Select o.Order_id, l.price, l.productCode
from Orders o
join LineItem l
  on l.Order_id = o.Order_id
where l.price = 10
union
Select o.Order_id, l.price, l.productCode
from Orders o
join LineItem l
  on l.Order_id = o.Order_id
where l.productCode = 12345
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that the lineitem in the first query wouldn't also appear in the the second.